# Framework using Keychain and UserDefaults shared between App and Keyboard Extension

Tags: ios, frameworks

I have a dynamic Framework which uses Keychain and UserDefaults to store its data. I want to use this Framework in an App and its Keyboard extenstion but I am having trouble making it work.

I turned on Keychain Sharing capability (with same group name) in both App and Extension and also turned on App Groups in both (also with same group name)

My usage is that in both App and Extension I instantiate a singleton class that stores its "activation" info in Keychain and UserDefaults. When I activate this class in App I don't see it active in Extension. I blame UserDefaults for this.

What is the right setting so that this class can see its Keychain and UserDefaults data both in App and also in Extension.

Comment: Does the Framework have to use UserDefaults(suiteName: "app_group_name") for writing and reading from/to defaults? Instead of UserDefaults.standard